# CSS in sharepoint

Tags: css, sharepoint, document, wss-3.0

I need to apply a CSS to a Sharepoint site (WSS3.0) based on the theme applied to a site.
The CSS would be saved at root site in 'Document Library'.
How do I apply the CSS programmatically on the page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Put in the page layout or master page.
E.g.

```
<SharePointWebControls:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistrationMyCSS" name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/~language/Core Styles/myCSS.css %>" runat="server"/>
```

Programatically changing it requires you to modify the control on page load. Not sure how well it would work though.

Comment: What do you think about Hari's desire to keep it in a document library?

Comment: I assumed that the document library he was talking about was the Style Library. I guess ya could? Though it would give access to mess with it to a lot more people.